# Unary operator on anonymous function in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am seeing following syntax:

```
auto anonym1 = [] (float a, float b) { return max(a, b); };
auto anonym2 = [] (float a, float b) { return min(a, b); };
auto anonymSel = x > y ? +anonym1 : +anonym2;
```

If I have written above anonymSel as below, it also compiles with clang c++14.

```
auto anonymSel = x > y ? anonym1 : anonym2;
```

**Note:** x and y are float variables.

Code comment says, for Visual C++ compilation '+' is added. I want to understand what this '+' is doing here.

Comment: Long story short, the two operands to the conditional operator need to have compatible types, so the author has used `+` to "promote" them from their [distinct] lambda types, into [compatible] function pointer types. Details per the duplicate.

Comment: If that's all the code comment says, though, then that's a bug: the comment should be improved to _really_ explain what the unary `+` is for.